# How to solve this problem while installing Ubuntu in my laptop with FreeDOS?

Tags: system-installation

I got a new laptop with FreeDOS in it. I'm trying to install Ubuntu in it. Whenever I'm selecting the device to boot from, this error is occurring. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to boot the live system ("try out Ubuntu" instead of install)? Which Ubuntu release do you have?

Comment: Are you sure your RAM is OK? (try run memtest86)

Comment: @takkat No. I couldn't try the system even. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It indeed may be a RAM issue or another hardware incompatibility - if the memtest did not fail try if you have more luck with an 18.04.1 live system (newer hadware may be better supported).

Comment: Its somewhere in here. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/init/do_mounts.c#L381

Answer (score 6, accepted):

re-download the ISO over a more stable connection. It said something about junk in the archive so the download probably corrupted.

Comment: It is better to check the checksums of the downloaded image to make sure the issue lies there and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

See the first line it says `Initramfs unpacking failed : junk in the uncompressed archive` that means your image has some junk or is corrupted . Download the image again and perform a check on it such as `md5sum` and when it matches with the key on the website you can proceed to make a bootable from it. You can find the md5sum string on the download page.